# declare static variable performance

Tags: c, linux, performance, gcc, static

In C Linux , I can declare variable as static into function , and it init only once and each time the CPU will see that declaration again it will be skip , or declare globally

Witch one of those function will have better performance ?

```
void increase_x()
{
    static int x =0;
    x+=1;
}


static int x = 0 ;
void increase_x()
{
    x+=1;
}
```

Comment: In compiled C implementations, the CPU does not see the declaration. The source code is translated into instructions, and the compiler that does that translation handles static declarations by building them into the data of the program, not giving the CPU instructions that it needs to skip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference. You can even see this in a diff of the disassembly of the compiled code:

```
< localstatic:     file format elf64-x86-64
---
> globalstatic:     file format elf64-x86-64
107c107
<     1131:     8b 05 dd 2e 00 00       mov    0x2edd(%rip),%eax        # 4014 <x.0>
---
>     1131:     8b 05 dd 2e 00 00       mov    0x2edd(%rip),%eax        # 4014 <x>
109c109
<     113a:     89 05 d4 2e 00 00       mov    %eax,0x2ed4(%rip)        # 4014 <x.0>
---
>     113a:     89 05 d4 2e 00 00       mov    %eax,0x2ed4(%rip)        # 4014 <x>
```

Answer (score 1):

Runtime performance should be identical between the two versions.

However, in the first snippet `x` is only visible within the body of `increase_x` - there's no way for the rest of the program to use its value.

You could change `increase_x` to return the new value of `x`:

```
int increase_x()
{
  static int x = 0;
  return x += 1;
}
```

It depends on how you intend to use the value of `x`, though.